# How to populate a form with specific names

Tags: vb.net

I'm wondering how I would go about writing a code that takes whatever the user typed in the two textboxes, `RK_txt_name_1` and `RK_txt_name_2`, and upon clicking a button called `RK_btn`, populates a textbox named `RK_txt_Space` with the following:

The first person's name was [whatever `RK_txt_name_1` corresponds to] and the second persons name is [whatever was typed into `RK_txt_name_2`] .

P.S. What, in your opinion, is the best resource to learn Visual Basic coding?

Comment: You're not going to get much help around here with questions like that because that is not what this site is for.  SO is for specific programming problems, not for teaching you the fundamentals or recommending resources.  You should find a forum site dedicated to VB.NET, not a Q&A site like SO.  Come back here when you have advanced a bit more and run into specific issues that you can describe to us and we can reproduce.  What you're asking here is covered by beginners tutorials, which you can find with a simple web search,

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

You access the value of the TextBoxes using their [.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  I'd use [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf3d0ccc(v=vs.110).aspx) to build your message in the final TextBox.  Something like...

```
Private Sub RK_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RK_btn.Click
    Dim msg As String = "The first person's name was {0} and the second persons name is {1}."
    RK_txt_Space.Text = String.Format(msg, RK_txt_name_1.Text, RK_txt_name_2.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

on the `click event` of `RK_btn` write single line of code to populate your text box with desired text.

```
RK_txt_Space.Text = "The first person's name was " + 
                     RK_txt_name_1.Text + " and the second persons name is " +  
                     RK_txt_name_2.Text
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Rick.Jaki Please accept the answer if it helped you..